# Inverse of airy function

Tags: matlab, math-software

I was implementing this function in MATLAB:  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNula.png)

But what will be the mathematical formula of inverse airy function.

Comment: For what domain. The airy function does not have a general unique inverse (try plotting it in Matlab). However, for the domain $[-1, \infty]$ a uniques inverse does exist.

Comment: For finite domain for example [-0.5,0.5]. Is there any formula of inverse airy function with the help i can implement it in MATLAB or Is there  any other method to plot it in MATLAB.